# Laravel requires php56-mcrypt, but I can't install php56-mcrypt

Tags: php, laravel, homebrew

I'm trying to get an old Laravel project running, but when I try running `composer install`, I get this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.32 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.32].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.32 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v5.0.32 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.0.3 requires illuminate/console 5.0.x -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.32].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.0.3 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper[v2.0.3].
```

The `php` executable I'm using is located here:

`/usr/local/Cellar/php@5.6/5.6.30_6/bin/php`

And I've added `extension=mcrypt.so` to every `php.ini` I could find (including one I put at the root of the Laravel project).

I have no idea if this is related (there appears to be a dozen or more php versions scattered throughout my Mac).

So I've been trying to install mcrypt but every answer I've found seems to be outdated. This is what I've tried:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt
```

Output: `Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt"`

```
brew install php@5.6 -with-mcrypt=mcrypt
```

This seems to install successfully but doesn't fix the error.

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install php56-mcrypt
```

Output: `Error: No available formula with the name "php56-mcrypt"`

How am I supposed to install `php56-mcrypt` on a Mac?

Comment: These installs saved me many times on Mac... https://php-osx.liip.ch/

Comment: What version of PHP is your server running?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Yesterday I had it running `5.6` using a symlink in `~/bin`. Today it appears that symlink isn't being found in my path (?), so I'm using `7.1.7` located at `/usr/bin/php` (which I can't move or delete even with `sudo`).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:- `brew install php56-mcrypt --without-homebrew-php`

And add this extension in your `/private/etc/php.ini` :-

extension=`"/usr/local/Cellar/php56-mcrypt/5.6.x/mcrypt.so"`

Edit:- Try adding tap first as follows:- `brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php` and than run the install command.

Comment: Running that `brew install` results in a failure with this error:

`Error: No available formula with the name "php56-mcrypt"`

Comment: You should replace `/usr/local/Cellar/php56-mcrypt/5.6.x` with the output of `brew --prefix php56-mcrypt`; it’ll give you a version-less path that’ll work even if you upgrade `php56-mcrypt`.